# Chrome shows "Failed to load PDF document" in online server but works fine in offline server

Tags: php

I'm trying to generate PDF file using mPDF. Chrome loads the PDF file in offline server as it should but shows below error in online server.

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ylwJE.png)

Mozilla however works fine both online and offline. Here is my code:

```
$pdf = new PDF();
  $title = $pdf->setStudentData($_GET)->generatePDFTitle();
  $header = $pdf->setStudentData($_GET)->generatePDFHeader();
  $footer = $pdf->generatePDFFooter();
  $getPDFData = $pdf->setStudentData($_GET)->generateStudentPDF();
  ob_clean();
  $savePDF = new mPDF();
  $savePDF->SetHTMLHeader($header);
  $savePDF->SetHTMLFooter($footer);
  $savePDF->SetTitle($title);
  $savePDF->WriteHTML($getPDFData); 
  $savePDF->Output($title.'.pdf', 'I');
  ob_end_flush();
```

Comment: I bet there is some warning generated which destroys the pdf.

Comment: If I download the corrupted PDF file and open it notepad there does seem to be a lot of warning showing up

Comment: You said it, if it works on localhost but not on hosting then there is something wrong with the hosting configuration.

Comment: check what the warnings / errors you're getting are and see if they're relevant. Without knowing any of that content, or anything about your server it's hard to give any more specific advice. Basically, the advice we can give amounts to: debug your code, check for errors, google the errors if you don't understand them, if you still don't understand them after that then post the info here in case anyone can help.